# Upcast child entity to parent do not work c#

Tags: c#, wpf, fluent-nhibernate

I can't do Upcast Child to Parent.
I have two classes:

```
public class PasswordEntity{
       protected string _password;

       public virtual string Password
        {
            get => _password;
            set => _password = value;
        }
```

And:

```
public class PasswordEntityWrapper : PasswordEntity{

 public override string Password
        {
            get => _password;
            set => SetProperty(ref _password, value);
        }
```

In ViewModel i try to Upcast from PasswordEntityWrapper to PasswordEntity like that:

```
public class PasswordInfoViewModel {

        private PasswordEntityWrapper _selectedItem;

        public PasswordEntityWrapper SelectedItem
        {
            get => _selectedItem;
            set => SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value);
        }
        public void DeleteEntity()
        {
            PasswordEntity item = (PasswordEntity)SelectedItem as PasswordEntity;
            _statefulRepository.Delete(item);
        }
```

But the _statefulRepository.Delete() method passes an Item of type PasswordEntityWrapper .

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSvPB.png)

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: IMHO, you are confusing CASTING to the base type and creating a NEW INSTANTCE of the base type.
You cast PasswordEntityWrapper to PasswordEntity.
The variable of the PasswordEntity type will contain a reference to the object. But the object, as it was of the PasswordEntityWrapper type, so remains.
By the way, this does not require the "as" operator - such a cast is done automatically. You can immediately do `_statefulRepository.Delete (SelectedItem);`

Comment: Perhaps you need something slightly different.
But it is not clear from your explanations.
Describe in more detail what you need to implement.
But not how you are trying to implement it.

Comment: @EldHasp I have an Entity for Fluent-Nhibernate: PasswordEntity. Which contains only public virtual Properties. 
I made a Wrapper for this Entity, which contains additional functionality. So in the code I work with PasswordEntityWrapper, but when saving/deleting to the database I want to do an upcast to PasswordEntity

Comment: Based on your explanation, no transformation is needed for this.
For the methods to work, you need entities of type PasswordEntity.
Passing into methods entities derived from PasswordEntity should not break their work.

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I expected, but for some reason it doesn't work that way. I need exactly the PasswordEntity type. But I can't convert PasswordEntityWrapper type to PasswordEntity type. - You can see it on the screenshot. I don't understand why it doesn't work that way.

Comment: Casting is not a conversion!
Example `object obj = 1;` Inside obj will be int.
The same is true for your case.
You write "doesn't work" - how is this manifested?
The method accepted SelectedItem and what happens next?

Comment: public void Delete<T>(T item)
        {

                Session.BeginTransaction();
                    Session.Delete(item);
}

Comment: I need PasswordEntity because I have Mapping to DB to PasswordEntity.

Comment: in the case of object obj = 1;
When passing obj to the delete(object myObject) method, I don't expect an error.
If I do this: delete(obj ) - I don't think the compiler will say that I passed it int instead of obj.

Comment: IMHO, "Mapping to DB to PasswordEntity" should work with any PasswordEntity derivative.
I can't imagine the reason why it won't work.
Perhaps you need an entity of this collection to remove from a collection.
And it's not even about what type she is.
If it were PasswordEntity, it wouldn't work anyway.

You can convert the derived type to a new PasswordEntity instance.
The best way to do this is to set a method in the PasswordEntity.
But I don't think this will solve the problem.

The problem, most likely, is in the methods themselves working with the database.